# How can I calculate time to interactive client-side?

Tags: javascript, performance, navigation-timing-api, rum

Chrome's Lighthouse tool and WebPageTest offer "time-to-interactive" (TTI) metrics.

Google offers [a minimal definition of TTI](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/time-to-interactive):

> Time to Interactive is defined as the point at which layout has stabilized, key webfonts are visible, and the main thread is available enough to handle user input.
>
> Note that this metric is in early phases and is subject to change.

WebPageTest [breaks them into "time to first interactive" and "time to consistently interactive"](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/docs/Metrics/TimeToInteractive.md):

> Time to Consistently Interactive Calculation
>
> - Start looking for TTI at the larger of first contentful paint or DOM Content Loaded
> - Look for the first interactive window where there is a contiguous period of 5 seconds fully contained within the interactive window with no more
>     than 2 in-flight requests
> - TTI is the start of the interactive window from step 2 or the search starting point, whichever is later Time to
>
> First Interactive Calculation
>
> - Start looking for TTI at the larger of first contentful paint or DOM Content Loaded
> - Look for the first interactive window where there is a contiguous period of 5 seconds fully contained within the interactive window regardless of the number of in-flight requests
> - TTI is the start of the interactive window from step 2 or the search starting point, whichever is later

I would like to calculate WebPageTest's two different TTI metrics client-side and send them back to an API (for [RUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_user_monitoring) purposes).

Is such a calculation possible with current JavaScript APIs? If so, how?

**Update:**

I haven't found a satisfactory client-side solution, but I have found a more [in-depth definition of TTI](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GGiI9-7KeY3TPqS3YT271upUVimo-XiL5mwWorDUD4c/preview#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleChromeLabs offers a [polyfill for the TTI metric](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/tti-polyfill).

Browsers will eventually expose the metric via built-in APIs:

> Note: this snippet is a temporary workaround, until browsers implement level 2 of the Performance Observer spec and include the `buffered` flag.